# Solving an absolute value inequality with a negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$8-|2x-1|\ge 6$$

I watched the Khan Academy video on absolute value inequalities, however I still don't understand what I would do in this situation with the $$8-$$ in front of it. Taking what I learned from the video I believe that this inequality can be rewritten as: $$8-|2x-1|\le -6$$ or $$8-|2x-1|\ge 6$$

Where would I go from here with that 8 and negative sign. I imagine that the 8 would be subtracted from the LHS and RHS..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need move the terms from left to right or right to left(change the sign), so you get
$$8-6\geq |2x-1|$$
that is $$|2x-1|\leq 2$$
then solve this inequality.

Comment: Rewriting it the way I did was unnecessary?

Comment: in fact your way is to multiply $-1$ to both sides of your equation and change the inequality sign, so you can do it like this: multiply $-1$(remember to change the inequality sign), the equation becomes $-8+|2x-1|\leq -6$, then add $8$ to both sides, we get $|2x-1|\leq -6+8=2$. the same result.

Comment: if you want substract $8$, you can add $-8$ on both sides of your original equation, then get $8-|2x-1|-8\geq 6-8$, that is $-|2x-1|\geq -2$, then multiply $-1$ to both sides, get $|2x-1|\leq 2$.

Comment: The second method you just posted is how I started to do it, I just got stuck and now i realize that  I should've multiplied both sides by (-1)

Answer (score 1):

The route described in the answer of Martial is very handsome.

More generally discern two cases that do not overlap and together cover the whole 'thing'. Here you can choose for:

1) $2x-1>0$ and $8-(2x-1)\geq6$

2) $2x-1\leq0$ and $8-(1-2x)\geq6$

Solving 1) you find $\frac{1}{2}<x\leq\frac{3}{2}$

Solving 2) you find $-\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq\frac{1}{2}$

Combining the answers gives $-\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq\frac{3}{2}$ as final solution.